# Filtering graphQL query on a nested field

Tags: graphql

Using the Uniswap-v3 interactive playground (URL below), I'm trying to list some swaps, except those where symbol is "DAI".  I've checked a lot of answers but can't figure out the correct syntax. Below is my current query. I have no error message, but am still getting "DAI" in the results. Any help welcome!

```
swaps(first: 50, orderBy: timestamp
) {

  pool {
    token0 {
      id
      symbol (ne: "DAI")
    }
  }
 }
}
 

URL: https://thegraph.com/hosted-service/subgraph/uniswap/uniswap-v3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation , the `swap` query has a `where` argument which is in the type of `Swap_filter` to allow you to define the filter conditions of the swaps.

Just playing around it and found that the result list that you want can be achieved by :

```
{
  swaps(first: 10 orderBy: timestamp 
   where:{
    token0_ :{
      symbol_not : "DAI"
    }
  }
  ) {
  pool {
    token0 {
      id
      symbol
    }
  }
 }
}
```

or

```
{
  swaps(first: 10 orderBy: timestamp 
   where:{
    token0_ :{
      symbol_not_in : ["DAI"]
    }
  }
  ) {
  pool {
    token0 {
      id
      symbol
    }
  }
 }
}
```